# SPL1048:E(L5), Unexpected text ';' in place of SPL statement

Tags: teradata

According to the Teradata [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn%7ElAaKSORpulwFMg/bp_GE%7EBlGFTwphePogArIA) BEGIN and END control statements can have labels. However, trying to create a following stored procedure

```
create multiset table table_1
(
    id int not null,
    val int
) unique primary index(id);

create procedure test_sp(IN p1 int, IN p2 INT)
L1: BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(:p1,:p2);
END L1;
```

gives me the following error:

SPL1048:E(L5), Unexpected text ';' in place of SPL statement. SPL1027:E(L5), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like an 'END' keyword between ';' and the
CREATE PROCEDURE Command Failed.

Without the labels "L1", the code works just fine. On the other hand, having labels inside the procedure works:

```
replace procedure test_sp(IN p1 int, IN p2 INT)
BEGIN
    L1: BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(:p1,:p2);
    END L1;
END;
```

Is this a configuration setting, or an error in the documentation?

Comment: The error is probably not related to the labels. Your code runs fine for me. But line 5 `SPL1048:E(L5)` which caused the error doesn't exists in your create.

Comment: I suspect this is a client issue, and the CREATE PROCEDURE request submitted to the database was truncated at the first ';' - and it's referenced as Line 5 only because there are some blank lines included in the request.

Comment: It's possible that your client executes one statement closed by ";" at a time, which is why the first set may have failed.

Comment: I've just tested another client (Teradata SQL Assistant) and it works as expected. Definitely a Nexus Query Chameleon issue. Thank you.